# Sage Pay 4021 Error

Tags: magento, payment, opayo

I am getting "INVALID. 4021 : The Card Range not supported by the system." in magento website while transaction. Please let me know how can I resolve this

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is that Sage Pay do not recognise the BIN range for that particular card (identified by the first 9 or so digits of the PAN). This maybe because the number was input incorrectly, the BIN range is no longer valid (eg: card withdrawn), or the range is so new that Sage Pay haven't received and applied the updated ranges yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to unblock the card range.  You can do this by clicking the “trashcan/rubbish bin” to the right of the card range.  Once you have clicked the “trashcan/rubbish bin” you will simply be asked to confirm you would like to remove the card range from your blocked list.

Once you have confirmed you would like to remove this card range it will no longer appear in your blocked list and you can process transactions using this range.

**If this does not fix it, check [this](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/16/36/blocking-card-ranges) out for more detail.**

Comment: Actually, that would throw a '4043 : The Vendor Rule Bases disallow this card range.' error